# vlookup if name is matched display employee id

Tags: vba, excel

Ive never used vlookups i have a spreedsheet not sure if this is the right function. I have two sheets

Sheet 1

first name    last name   username

Sheet 2

first name     last name      employee id business unit

I need in column D on sheet 1 to have employee id ive below. Pay no attention to column letters and sheets because i moved to another sheet to try getting this right.

=MATCH(B11,Sheet1!C:C,0)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So you realize you have to match both first and last names?  There are several ways to accomplish this depending on how many employees you have in sheet 2: a) small list could a two-column search using array formula; b) large list just create another column in both sheets joining last & first names and do a MATCH or VLOOKUP on them.

Since your needs are simple and to illustrate option (b):

1. Insert a column in both Sheet1 and Sheet2 after the "last name"; you should now have an empty column C in both sheets.
2. Assuming you have column headers in row one, and thus data starts in row two, set cell C2 in both sheets with function =B2&","&A2, then fill-down that formula on both sheets in all rows.
3. Set Sheet1 cell E2 to formula =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!C2, Sheet2!$C:$D, 2, False), and fill-down that formula in all rows.

Voila, employee IDs on Sheet1.  I do have to say this is so Excel 101.  There are all sorts of examples and tutorials on this easily found using even the most trivial Google searches.